# Crash Ajax Request When Use Slash In Url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I Have Simple Project For Test Ajax Request When Url Rewrited , Like This :

htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  



RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1
```

index.php :

```
<?php 

if (!isset($_GET['param'])){

    include('home.php');

}


if (isset($_GET['param'])){

include('tick.php');

}

?>
```

home.php :

```
<h1>HOME</h1>
```

tick.php :

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {    

     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/request.php", 
    dataType: "json",   
    data: {k_name:'book'},
        success: function (data) {

      //ghtml();

        }
      })

  }
```

request.php:

```
<?php 

require("config.inc.php");
require("Database.singleton.php");

$k_name=$_POST['k_name'];
$data = array();

//Connect To DB
    $db= new Database(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
    $db->connect();


    $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM table1 WHERE name=$k_name ";
    $rows = $db->fetch_array($sql);



    foreach($rows as $record){
        $data[] = array('id' => $record['id'], 'name' => $record['name']); 
    }



echo json_encode(array_values($data));
 ?>
```

When Url Is :

```
http://localhost/ajax/aaaa
```

**Note :my Folder Project Name Is Ajax.**

Ajax Request Work Well But When Use Slash In Url Like This :

```
http://localhost/ajax/aaaa/
```

Ajax Request Is Crashed,and I Now Must Use Framework To Beter Request Dispatching But I Dont Understand This Problem  Why Happened.

Comment: What do you mean "crashed"? What error are you getting?

Comment: my mean is when url is : http://localhost/ajax/aaaa ajax request return json data but add slash to url like this : http://localhost/ajax/aaaa/aaa  not return any data

Comment: my project in zip file : http://uplodha.ir/dl/93-04/files/ajax-test.zip

Answer (score 0):

You're not crashing AJAX. You're suffering from an [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability and a lack of any form of error handling in your code:

You're directly inserting your AJAX value into the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM table1 WHERE name=$k_name ";
                                               ^^^^^^^
```

which leads to queries like:

```
SELECT ... WHERE name=foo
```

Unless you have a field named `foo` in your table, this will cause a syntax error and kill your query. But since you have NO error handling whatsoever, you simply assume the query will never fail and proceed with bad data.

You've probably got your `fetch` calls spitting out PHP warnings about calling methods on  non-object being output. And since your calling JS code is expecting JSON back as a response, that error will cause JSON parse errors, blah blah blah.

In short, if you'd bothered having even minimal basic error handling, this could've been prevented:

```
if (query failed) {
   output json error message
} else {
   process query results
}
```

Never **EVER** assume success. Always assume failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise. There's exactly ONE way for a query to suceed, and a near infinite number of ways for it to fail. You'd be welcome in Las Vegas casinos, since you treat that 1-in-infinity chance as "guaranteed success".

Comment: name=$k_name  is a example and in real project i use escape and other algoritm for validation , but my problem with slash in url